# javascript check intersections reduce computational complexity

Tags: javascript, for-loop, complexity-theory

I have a list where is 500 000 objects, each object has a coordinate. I want to leave only unique objects in that list. In order to do that, I do following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < features.length; j++) {
      if (features[i].coord == features[j].coord) {
         features.splice(features.indexOf(features[j]), 1);
       }
    }
 }
```

But it is not efficient solution because it is very slow with complexity O(n^2). How can I leave only unique elements in a very fast way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash/map/table/whatever to deduplicate; the key (which will have to be a string) is a representation of the coordinate.

```
function deduplicate(features) {

    function magicalToString(coordinate) {
        return 'some string representation of the coordinate';
    }

    var table = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        table[magicalToString(features[i].coord)] = features[i];
    }

    var uniques = [];
    // potential optimization: uniques = new Array(Object.keys(table).length)
    // not guaranteed to be net faster; benchmark and measure.
    for (var k in table) {
        if (table.hasOwnProperty(k)) uniques.push(table[k]);
    }

    return uniques;
}
```

O(n).